# How do I get the name of a building at a given address?

Tags: google-maps

When I type into Google Maps `2208 15th Av W, Seattle` I see on the left hand side "At this location DESC Interbay Low Income Housing Program · 15th Ave W"

How do I get that information via an API?

Comment: You might wanna check out [Places](https://developers.google.com/places/)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to execute the following two requests:

1. Geocoding API for your address

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2208%2015th%20Av%20W%2C%20Seattle&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This request will return the latitude and longitude (47.63889409999999,-122.3761937).

2. Execute Places API text search request using coordinates from step 1

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=2208%2015th%20Av%20W%2C%20Seattle&location=47.63889409999999%2C-122.3761937&radius=20&type=establishment&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This request will return "DESC Interbay" (place ID ChIJm84xznYVkFQR1Xghym3KHQM).

For more details please refer to Places API documentation:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests